# How to make client app automatically connect to the server app with ServerSocket in Adobe AIR without typing IP and port?

Tags: sockets, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I use ServerSocket and Socket in ActionScript 3 to connect from Flash Player to AIR applicaion in LAN network.
The thing is, on the client player, I must type the server IP address to connect the AIR app. Is there any way to connect to the server automatically without typing IP address?

Comment: Sure. Your client app must already have address and port, hardcoded, so you won't need to type them.

Comment: The thing is the server IP can be changed. I want the client automatically find the server in the network, without know the server IP and port before.

Comment: Well, then. There are options. A) You can devise an external web service so your server app reports the exact **address:port** information there for clients to obtain later. Contras: web might not be available, also if your system is not a single instance, there will be complications. B) Client knocks on a possible range of LAN addresses and ports. You can figure client's IP via **NetworkInfo.findInterfaces()**. C) Keep the successful address:port combinations and ask for input **only** if the stored ones fail. This also compliments the B variant.